# Retrieve data where corresponding mapping is not found in one-to-many mapped field

Tags: spring, hibernate, hql, criteria

I am currently trying out Hibernate Criteria in my work.

Consider I have the following entities.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="form_table_name")
public class Forms extends Auditable 
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="FormID")
    private Long formID;

    @Column(name="FormTitle")
    private String formTitle;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "form", fetch = FetchType.EAGER , cascade = {CascadeType.ALL} , orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<FormsResponses> responses;
    ..........//rest of the code with fields, getters, setters etc.

@Entity
@Table(name="response_table_name")
public class FormsResponses extends Auditable 
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="ResponseID")
    private Long responseID;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="FormID")
    private Forms form;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="OnBehalfOf")
    private Users onBehalfOf;
    ..........//rest of the code
```

Consider I have the following data
*form_table_name*

```
FormID FormTitle
------ --------- 
1      Form1
2      Form2
```

*response_table_name*

```
ResponseID FormID OnBehalfOf
---------- ------ ----------
1          1         user1
2          1         user2
4          2         user2
```

I want to load the data from **Forms** entity, if and only if there are no records in **FormsResponses** corresponding to the value I pass for the 'onBehalfOf' field and 'formID'.

Say, my current 'onBehalf' value is 'user1'. I want to retrieve form1 and form2. But, a form should not be shown if it has 'user1' in its formsResponse mapped row. Or if a user has already attempted a form, it shouldn't be retrieved. In this case that form will be 'Form2' and for 'user2' it will be 'empty'

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Forms.class);
cr.createCriteria("responses", "res", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
            .add(Restrictions.eq("res.onBehalfOf.userID", userID));
            cr.add(Restrictions.sizeEq("responses", 0));
```

I tried this, but it doesn't serve my purpose. I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how your query should look like:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Forms.class, "frm");
c.createAlias("frm.responses", "res", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN);
c.createAlias("res.onBehalfOf", "beh", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN, Restrictions.eq("beh.userID", userID));
c.add(Restrictions.isNull("beh.userID"));
return c.list();
```

Comment: Sure. Will check and update. 

And by "beh.id" you mean "beh.userID", right?